# 3 processes start taking up all the CPU, computer overheats. How do I shut them off?

Tags: overheating, cpu-load, systemd-journald

I have an old computer with Ubuntu 16.
When I'm working on it, I'm not signed in as Admin. A few days ago I did an update and since then, it's happened twice that after several hours of working, I notice the computer is overheating. It doesn't exactly freeze but it barely moves.
3 processes are taking up between 20 and 35% CPU each.
systemd-journald
rsysylogd-n
[kworker/0:2]
I try to order the processes to stop, but it tells me I don't have the proper privileges, without giving me a chance to login to Admin.
What do I do?

Comment: Overheating will cause the CPU to throttle down to as low as 800mhz, which will cause it to run slower and it appear to be running at 100% usage, which it is using 100% of 800mhz.  Post the output of `/proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: How hot is hot? Install `lm-sensors` and use the `sensors` command. Edit that into your question, along with `free -h` and `top`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the terminal for this.

First enter

```
top
```

Get the PIDs (first column)

Now enter (with or without sudo)

```
kill PID
eg.
kill 3184
```

The processes might be critical, so it is not wise to just stop everything without knowing what they are doing. Overheating might be indicative of a deeper problem ?

Also, how old is old ? Is RAM memory sufficient ? htop or glances might reveal more information. Is the swap full (best seen via htop)

Comment: Might also be an idea to remember when you last clean computer of dust.  Last couple of months, okay.